# Mapping inside monad

Tags: haskell, monads

```
f1 ∷ Int → Identity (Maybe String)
f1 x = Identity $ if even x then Just (show x) else Nothing

-- f1 4 = "4", f1 5 = Nothing etc.

f2 ∷ (Int → Identity (Maybe String)) → [Int] → Identity String

-- f2 [1..10] = "246810"
```

Now is it possible to implement f2 using [mapMaybeM](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-extras-0.5.11/docs/Control-Monad-Extra.html#v:mapMaybeM)?

--- EDIT ----------------------

Let me try and show you the actual problem behind this question.

```
g1 :: Type1 -> SomeT Maybe Type2
```

g2 needs to map over Just values and get rid of Maybe:

```
g2 :: (Type1 -> SomeT Maybe Type2) -> [Type1] -> SomeT Identity [Type2]
```

Comment: Regarding your update, should the `SomeT Maybe Type2`'s be `SomeT (Maybe Type2)`? And `SomeT Identity [Type2]` be `SomeT [Type2]`? If so, could you possibly elaborate on how my answer does not work to resolve this? I think `mapMaybeM` should indeed do precisely what you're looking for.

Comment: No, it should not.  SomeT is a transformer.  Perhaps you can give a code example using generic g1 and g2?

Comment: @punund Why don't you write down your exact problem here instead of `SomeT` and `Type1`.

Comment: It doesn't not really matter and will only complicate things.  `SomeT` is `ReaderT (CustomType1, CustomType2)` and `Type1` is `Int`.

Comment: @punund I updated my answer with an implementation working in `IdentityT`. I'm not sure it can be generalized to any transformer, though. Seeing that you're using `ReaderT`, though, there is a `mapReaderT`.

Comment: Thank you for your update.  It gives `IdentityT (Identity ["4","6","8","10"])` instead of `IdentityT (Identity "46810")`.  It should work for `ReaderT` as well, it is essentially identity if we don't invoke its functions.

Comment: @punund Updated. Missed the `concat`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mapMaybeM f1` would get you `[Int] -> Identity [String]`. Then you could use `fmap concat` for `Identity [String] -> Identity String` to concatenate the values.

Per your update, in case this is helpful:

```
f2 :: (Int -> IdentityT Maybe String) -> [Int] -> IdentityT Identity [String]
f2 f = mapIdentityT (fmap concat) . foldl (liftA2 (++)) (lift (return [])) . map (mapIdentityT (return . maybeToList) . f)
```

This works within `IdentityT` relying on `mapIdentityT`. I think the root problem is getting `[MT M a] -> MT M [a]` and I'm not sure this is possible in general - it may be dependent on properties of the transformer.